# Authentication to Db instance happening before getting db-auth-credentials - Why?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Our app is a NodeJS app. It needs to connect to a AWS-Db-Instance but with auth-credentials from AWS-vault. But facing a problem which is a generic nodejs issue of initializing `module.exports.db`

### Expected sequence:

Step1 : I must get the auth-credentials from AWS-vault(external dependency async call).

Step 2 : Use credentials from Step1 to connect to AWS-Db-Instance

### Actually happening (unexpected)

step2 (i.e. the authentication) completes before step1(i.e. initialization of the *db* variable in local.js).

### The Code :

**./src/app.js**

```
...
const config = require('../config')    
const query = require('./db/query')
...
```

**./config/index.js**

```
const local = require('./environment/local')
module.exports = local
```

**./environment/local.js**

```
const authService = require('../../src/helpers/vault-auth')    

module.exports = {    
  port: 3001,
  db: authService.getAuthCredentials()      
}
```

**./src/helpers/vault-auth.js**

```
    const vault = require("node-vault")({   apiVersion: "v1",   endpoint: 'https://gs-vault.xxxxxx.co.uk' });
    const roleId = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    const secretId = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    const databaseRole = 'some-path-resembling-custom-defined-role'
    
    
    function getAuthCredentials(){
        return   (async() => fetchCredentials())().then(result => result) //IIFE
    }

    async function fetchCredentials(){
    
        try {
            const result = await vault.approleLogin({
            role_id: roleId,
            secret_id: secretId,
            });

            vault.token = await result.auth.client_token; // Add token to vault object for subsequent requests.
            const { data } = await vault.read(databaseRole); // Retrieve the secret stored in previous steps
            const { username, password } = (data)        

            return { 
            'username': username, 
            'password': password, 
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return e;
        }
    }
module.exports = {
    getAuthCredentials : getAuthCredentials
}
```

**./src/db/query.js**

```
const db = require('./db')

module.exports = {
  sql: function(string, bind) {
    const options = {type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT}
    return db.query(string, {...options, bind})
  },
  insert: function(table, records) {
    return db.queryInterface.bulkInsert(table, records)
  }
}
```

**./src/db/db.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../../config')
const bus = require('../helpers/event-bus')
const logger = require('../helpers/logger')
const dbConfig = config.db

const db = new Sequelize(
  `postgres://${dbConfig.user}:${dbConfig.password}@${dbConfig.host}`,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: dbConfig.logging,
    pool: {
      max: 50
    }
  }
)

db.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info(`Connection to postgres://${dbConfig.user}:${dbConfig.host} has been established successfully.`)
    bus.emit('ready')
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    logger.info(`Unable to connect to postgres://${dbConfig.user}:${dbConfig.host}: ${err}`)
  })

module.exports = db
```

**Question :**

I don't intend to use Promises in any form like
`Promises.resolve(){...} or .then(.=>{})` unless thats the only way. But I'm ok with the async/await syntax. I am struggling with this and browsed many similar SO answers...but failed to make it work. Tried IIFE too.

What changes to the code must be done to get this thing fully working ? (Any minimal but complete workable NodeJS code example, not necessarily AWS related, is also fine which I might refer to)